# how can output data be in the form of a table on karatelabs

Tags: karate

I have a data as follows:
{ AgentID : Supermarket,
AgentPIN : 12345,
AgentTrxID : 11122334455,
AgentStoreID : 223355,
ProductID : AAKUU,
....}
how to make the output of the data can be in the form of a table when it is successful ?

example output :
|key       | value         |
|AgentID   | Supermarket   |
|AgentPIN  | 12345         |
|AgentTrxID| 11122334455   |
......
ResponseMessage : (00) Suksess

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question. are you trying to do testing or create tables ? karate is for testing. also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.